# Sort a PHP array moving up if condition is true

Tags: php

I have an array like this:

```
[
  [id: 1, urgent: true, marketplace: false],
  [id: 2, urgent: true, marketplace: true],
  [id: 3, urgent: false, marketplace: false]
]
```

The array is ordered (default) with `urgent`on top. What I need, is moving up all the rows that have `marketplace = true`.

I tried this, but do not works:

```
usort($f, function($a, $b) {
  if ($a['marketplace'] || $b['marketplace']) {
    return 1;
  }
  return 0;
});
```

Comment: Do you mean that `marketplace` has a higher sort priority than `urgent`, but in the case of two items having the same `marketplace` value, `urgent=true` should come before `urgent=false`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
usort($f, function($a, $b) {
  if ($a['marketplace'] == $b['marketplace']) {
    return 0;
  }
  return $a['marketplace'] ? 1 : -1;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$data=[
    ['id'=> 1, 'urgent'=> true, 'marketplace'=> false],
    ['id'=> 2, 'urgent'=> true, 'marketplace'=> true],
    ['id'=> 3, 'urgent'=> false, 'marketplace'=> false],
    ['id'=> 3, 'urgent'=> false, 'marketplace'=> true],
    ['id'=> 3, 'urgent'=> false, 'marketplace'=> false],
    ['id'=> 3, 'urgent'=> false, 'marketplace'=> true],
    ['id'=> 3, 'urgent'=> false, 'marketplace'=> false],
];

echo"<pre>";
//print_r($data);


$trueArray=array();
$falseArray=array();
$i=0;
foreach($data as $row){
    if($row['marketplace']==true){
        $trueArray[$i]=$row;
    }
    else{
        $falseArray[$i]=$row;
    }
    $i++;
}

//print_r($trueArray);
//print_r($falseArray);

$result=array_merge($trueArray,$falseArray);
print_r($result);
```

added some more values for more valid testing. The output is this :

```
    Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [urgent] => 1
            [marketplace] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [urgent] => 
            [marketplace] => 1
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [urgent] => 
            [marketplace] => 1
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [urgent] => 1
            [marketplace] => 
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [urgent] => 
            [marketplace] => 
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [urgent] => 
            [marketplace] => 
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [urgent] => 
            [marketplace] => 
        )

)
```

The fields with marketplace true are on top of the new array.

Answer (score -1):

Try combining your condition:

```
usort( $arr, function ( $a, $b ) {
    return ($a['urgent'] || $b['urgent']) && ($a['marketplace'] || $b['marketplace']);
} );
```